# Nullability of an array in Eclipse

Tags: java

suggest the following code in Eclipse 4.30:

```
    public void doSomething(@NonNull SomeType[] pArray) {
       // Whatever
    }
```

If I enable checks for nullability (Preferences/Java Compiler/"Errors/Warnings"/Null analysis/Enable annotation based null-analysis), then I notice the following:

The Compiler takes the parameter type as "an array of SomeType elements, all of which are non-null", or in other words an array of @NonNull SomeType. (If you don't believe me, change SomeType to byte, and notice the error message, because byte is a primitive type, so @NonNull byte makes no sense.)

Which is all very well. However, I would like to tell the compiler, that the array itself is non-null. Is there any possibility to express this? (Let's say @NonNull (SomeType[]) pArray.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, of course. There are 2 layers of nullity to this story. In fact, with, say, an `Object[][]`, there are *3* different nullity.

It could be a nullable reference to an array, which contains definitely-not-null arrays of definitely-not-null objects.

It could be a definitely-not-null reference to an array, which contains nullable refs to arrays of definitely-not-null objects.

And so on.

The syntax to specify at each level is like this:

```
@Nullable String @NonNull [] x
```

That means: a definitely-not-null reference to an array of nullable strings.

Each `[]` can be prefixed with annotations, applying to that 'layer'.

The same '3 layers' situation applies to a list of a list of objects, but the syntax is a lot more obvious there:

```
@NonNull List<@Nullable String>
```

Is the equivalent.

**BIG CAVEAT**: This requires the annotation to marked as applying to `TYPE_USE`. Many nullity annotations were created in the java 1.5 days which did not have `TYPE_USE`; only `PARAMETER` and `METHOD` and `FIELD`. Many nullity annotations, as a consequence, still only target P/M/F instead of T_U. For these, what you want simply isn't possible. Update to a better nullity annotation system, or embrace how they work.

Some major annotation libraries that work on the basis of `TYPE_USE`:

| Library | Annotation class |
| --- | --- |
| [*Eclipse Java development tools (JDT)*](https://eclipse.dev/jdt/) | [`org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNull.html) |
| [*Checker Framework*](https://checkerframework.org/) | [`org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/NonNull.html) and [`PolyNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/PolyNull.html) |
| [*JSpecify*](https://jspecify.dev/) | [`org.jspecify.annotations.Nullable`](https://jspecify.dev/docs/api/org/jspecify/annotations/Nullable.html) |

Comment: Thank you, very much! The syntax Type @NonNull [] works perfectly.